# submit value to page as get method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to submit `myId` as a value of id to `example.php` page and if the page `example.php` return a variable `$=success`, then a alert will show how to do that

```
function(isConfirm){  
    myId="4";
    $.get("example.php",{id: myId});
}
```

Comment: There are examples in [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function(isConfirm){  
    myId="4";
    $.get("example.php",{id: myId}).done(function(data){
      if( data == 'success' ) { alert( 'Success!' ); }
    });
}
```